# Can I use python3 classes inside a Flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm designing a Flask app that graphs some weather data for several cities. It makes sense to me to use a "City" class that handles the fetching and parsing of the data every time the page is loaded. However, what I'm not sure about is how Flask would handle these instances. Is Flask "smart" enough to know to release the memory for these instances after the page is served? Or will it just gradually consume more and more memory?

Alternatively, would I just be able to create a single global class instance for each city OUTSIDE of the "@app.route" functions that I could use whenever a page is requested?

The deployment server will be Windows IIS using FastCGI, in case that matters at all.

Comment: I don't really understand what this has to do with flask, flask doesn't handle memory management, that is all handled by the python runtime, likely in your case the CPython runtime. And python handles instances of user-defined classes exactly the same way it handles all other objects, and *everything* is an object, so you might as well ask, "can I use objects in my flask app?"

Comment: I explained a little more in a comment below. But basically, my experience is scripts and not applications, so I was curious about how to handle the classes within a framework when the memory will not be released until the app is restarted. I know HOW to set up the classes and that it is possible do so in Flask framework. So I guess my biggest question was just, SHOULD I. And if so, what are the best practices to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Again, you are essentially asking if you should use objects in your program. Which, in Python, is essentially impossible to avoid, because *everything is an object* -- so `int`, `str`, `list` etc... There is nothing special about a user-defined class in that regard. Now, if your question is how to avoid memory leaks in general, it would probably help if you gave some sort of example of exactly what you are doing. Python objects will be garbage collected if they are no longer referenced. Indeed, making global objects is one of the things that would guarantee that they won't be reclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is "just" a framework. It is still executed and managed by the "normal" Python interpreter so the question "how Flask would handle these instances" is nonexistent.

Define classes and use their instances as you would in any other Python project/snippet, however it might be beneficial to think *where* to define them.

It will not make sense inside a route since the class will be redefined every time a request is received, but the *how* is exactly the same.

Comment: I guess the real reason I'm asking is because I'm used to defining python SCRIPTS and not APPLICATIONS. So when the script is over, all the memory is released. In my mind with an application, the program is always running and so all those instances would could continue to mount up until the application is restarted.

Comment: @WillBlanton If you create the instance within the route then it will be deleted when handling of the request is over (as long as you don't keep a reference to it anywhere)